# IE9 renders my web site as IE7. How to make it render as IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

IE9 renders my web site as IE7. How to make not to make assumptions?

Comment: Stupid question I'm sure, but this is happening to just your site, not all sites you visit, right?

Comment: Can you provide the address of your site?

Comment: Depends on the parameter domain name (WTF! o_O). See the spacing above the main buttons/menu and very bottom of the page. And the address. http://imgur.com/a/qBCdo no problem on the internet but the problem occurs only when i use custom localhost name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meta tag should do it:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

You can also send it out as an HTTP header

Comment: when i press f12 i see user ager ie9 and document ie7. i'm setting it to ie9 but when i restart ie, it says ie7 again. the meta tag did not helped at all.

Comment: Depends on the parameter domain name (WTF! o_O). See the spacing above the main buttons/menu and very bottom of the page. And the address. http://imgur.com/a/qBCdo no problem on the internet but the problem occurs only when i use custom localhost name. thus, now i'm using only the IP address.

Comment: By the way I think I found better one <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="edge">

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using and incorrect/malformed doctype tag. This is the usual trigger for this behavior.