# IE9 changes Browser Mode based using domain name or ip address for the url

Tags: web-development, browsers, internet-explorer-9

Update : Tested with IIS6 and IE9 the same problem persisted. using paulmorriss's advice the Browser mode and Document for the page were different, so this problem had nothing to do with IIS6 or 7 but with using IE9 ( Havent tried IE 7, 8 yet).

I am developing a site on my machine, and to allow others to view the progress it is being hosted under IIS7 on my  local machine. Sames pages look different with IE9 when using localhost,127.0.0.1 or the machine ip than when viewed using the machine name "xpc"

I saved the same page and folloing is the section when viewed with localhost,127.0.0.1 or my machine IP :

```
<META name="Author">
<META name="Copyright">
<META name="Description">
```

here is the same thing when viewed using http://xpc instead :

```
<META name=Author>
<META name=Copyright>
<META name=Description>
```

There is no hardocing of domain name in any way anywhere (as far I have been able to verify), so why is the same page being served in two different ways? Everything works fine when I launch the site from VS2010 development server.

Also pages looked identical when viewed with FireFox. So my guess is IIS7 is serving differently for IE(9), but why?

Thank you

Edit :
[Related](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/ie9-renders-my-web-site-as-ie7-how-to-make-it-render-as-ie9) : Tried it but still no joy, force refreshing the page and looking at the source I can see the meta tag but nothing changed, changing to ip adress shows fine.

Comment: I haven't got IE9, but if you press F12 in IE7 or IE8 you get the developer tools. At the top it tells you the browser mode and document mode. What does this say when you access the web page in the different ways?

Comment: @paulmorriss : thank you, tried it with IIS6 and using your advice, it is IE9 that is interpretting the same page differently based on the ip or domain name of the url!

Comment: Could you use an `X-UA-Compatible` header to force the mode for testing purposes by adding this meta tag? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried adding that meta tag but still no joy! the site looks right when accessed using ip address! What does ip adress has to do with page document mode?!

Comment: IE maintains a [compatibility view list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567845%28VS.85%29.aspx) that determines what mode to use for each page based on the IP/URL. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651278/how-can-a-page-in-ie-render-differently-between-cassini-and-iis7) for details of discrepancies with display mode between servers. I suggest [displaying all websites in compatibility view](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1220-internet-explorer-compatilbility-view-all-websites.html) in IE9, then testing both URLs again to see if it's related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solved the problem :

leaving IE9 out got the site to be displayed as it was seen before IE9. [Used this MS Refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Edit: by leaving IE9 out I mean instead of using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10" >
```

from the refrence above, I used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5, IE=8, IE=10" >
```

and it worked.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "leaving IE9 out"?

Comment: @GotDibbs : I updated the answer, thanks for pointing this out. When I reread my answer I had no idea what I meant, had to do some diggging!